# Make a smooth tile texture with Voronoi texture run through a colour ramp node

Tags: texturing, procedural

I'm making a tile texture using voronoi texture run through a colour ramp node. The red colour part is not blending into the rest of the colour ramp. Any thoughts how to fix this?[image]

Comment: Use a drawing software to draw how you want it to actually look, the solution depends on that.

Answer (score 2):

Your *Exponent* value is way too high. Basically the *Minkowski* distance should be the *Chebychev* distance for the *Exponent* reaching $\infty$, but Blender seems to compute this not so well. Actually there is a blending of the red color into the white starting in the middle, however the red square increases in size with higher exponents and simply covers the gradient.

But what you might have already guessed here is since I mention it: what you rather want to use instead of *Minkowski* with a very high exponent is *Chebychev* to get the result you want:

[image: chebychev]

You can get something similar with *Minkowski* and an *Exponent* of perhaps 16, but the corners are a bit round then. Everything above 16 makes the center square overlap the gradient.

[image: minkowski exp 16]

Another way how you can get sharper corners with *Minkowski* is using the *F2* festure instead of *F1*. Then you can even use an *Exponent* of 32. You only have to flip the colors on the *Color Ramp* and adjust the sliders to your liking.

[image: minkowski F2]

Note that I have moved the sliders just arbitrary to get similar results, I did not try to make them all match as good as possible.

Also I do not know if you wanted the red to start from the center (because the red slider was fully to the left) or if there should be a visible red square in the middle. If so, then you can of course adjust the position of the red slider as well. With the setups shown above the gradient will then start at the border of the red square, not be just overlaying the gradient from the center. By the way, but if you use *Minkowski* with your high exponent, as soon as you move the red slider far enough so that the square gets larger, than you can see the gradient again from the square edge.

Comment: Thank you Gordon - appreciate those insights. The rub, however, is that I need those tight rounded corners that, AFAICT, are only offered by Minkowski with a high exponent. I suppose I'll need to rethink the approach. Thanks again.

Comment: @JKCapeTown Hmmmm... what about using two Voronoi textures: one with the black and white part, another with a red to white part. And then multiplying them together in a _Mix Color_ node? Like this: [Minkowski × Chebychev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtG3n.jpg)

Comment: Yes, that could work. Thanks again!